# How to check customer paypal amount before payment using access token

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

**we are using future payment so i want to verify amount is sufficient or not**

We are using the Paypal Payments gateway with their Rest APIs And i want to konw.How to check paypal amount before payment.because We are using automatic payment via token. So, my question is whether their is a way to check if a particular payment is possible before executing it.

Comment: Note only Vote dawn is not solution.